# I get Error: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable'

Tags: angular

Here I have my two methods in my service. I am new to this, so I am not sure what subscribe method does, but all I know I can't build my project without it. If i comment these two functions, then ng serve, then uncomment, and let it refresh changes, it works. But I can't build project. How do I change the code, so I don't get those errors and build project successfully?

```
public delete(patient: Patient): Observable<Patient> {
    return this.http.delete<Patient>(`${this.deleteOneUrl}/${patient.id}`).subscribe();
}

public addPatient(patient: Patient): Observable<Patient> {  
    return this.http.post<Patient>(this.addOneUrl, patient).subscribe();
}
```

> ERROR in src/app/patient.service.ts(30,3): error TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>     Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
>   src/app/patient.service.ts(38,5): error TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.

Comment: There is a mismatch in the return type & whats actually returned. Ideally you should be returning an `Observable`. Therefore no need of the `subscribe()` to be there at all. These two methods could then be observed (subscribed to) from somewhere else, ideally from another component.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By calling `subscribe()`, you are getting `Subscription` object instead of the `Observable` (that you get just by calling the `delete`/`post` method).

Either change the return type to `Subscription`, or return the `Observable` (drop the `.subscribe()`).

Usually you should return the observable from your service and subscribe later (in some click handler or even in template). By subscribing in the service, you will trigger the http call immediately, while returning the observable is lazy, and the http call will be triggered later when you subscribe to it).

Comment: I've changed return type to Subscription. It works in developer mode, but I still can't run 'ng build -prod' successfully, now I get an error: ERROR in src/app/patients/patients.component.ts(28,41): error TS2551: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you mean 'unsubscribe'?
src/app/patient-detail/patient-detail.component.ts(33,41): error TS2551: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you mean 'unsubscribe'?

so program works fine, but compiler sees an error, and I believe it can't build a prod. version because of it.

Comment: When you return `Subscription`, you already subscribed to the observable behind it. The error is about you are trying to call it again.

Comment: It's like, if I used some sort of "suppress errors" it should've worked, but that's an undesirable workaround.

Comment: I would drop the `subscribe()` call from your service and leave the return type as `Observable`.

Comment: Problem with production build is that is uses AoT, which kinda evaluates the code when building. The error is there also in dev build, you just need to trigger that code manually (probably via some button click).

Comment: @MartinAdámek when we subscribe later - why we dont get subscription again ?

Comment: The thing is that you need to subscribe again on the observable, not on subscription (which is what you get from the observable.subscribe() method). And you will indeed get a new subscription from that.